# R: Cannot load data.table due to missing symbol _omp_set_num_threads

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R package with a list of imports and have never had a problem loading the latest version.  I have just added `data.table` to the list, and now cannot load the package.

**OS** : macOS Sierra 10.12.5/6

**gcc** :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

**Imports**

```
aws.s3,
data.table,
googledrive,
httr,
jsonlite,
lubridate,
plyr
RMixpanel,
rmongodb,
RPresto,
stringi,
stringr,
uuid
```

**Errors**

```
openmp-utils.c:50:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'omp_set_num_threads' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
omp_set_num_threads(1);
^
1 warning generated.

...

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/data.table/libs/datatable.so':
dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/data.table/libs/datatable.so, 6): Symbol not found: _omp_set_num_threads

Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/data.table/libs/datatable.so

Expected in: flat namespace in /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/data.table/libs/datatable.so

Error: loading failed
```

I have also tried moving `plyr` to be higher than `data.table`, but get the same error.  Any ideas for anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you just upgraded to 1.10.4-1 which is on CRAN yesterday?  In a fresh R session,  does `test.data.table()` work?  Suspect it's an install/upgrade issue.

Comment: That line is called when you fork using the `parallel` package.  Are you using `parallel` package?  It is something I've changed in this patch so I'm likely to blame.  Can we see your full installation output to see if it found openMP when installing please.

Comment: I see now.   My fault.  I didn't wrap the call in an #ifdef for when OpenMP is not available.  Hard to test things like this because we'd have to uninstall OpenMP to test it.

Comment: We need to see the full output of the installation to see which compiler and version you're using please. Which OS is this?   Basically : you don't have OpenMP so it's not going to work and I made a mistake in not letting it install without OpenMP.  I can fix with another patch, but it would then install single-threaded for you, so you want OpenMP anyway.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for finding. Will track on GitHub for when update is available. What previous release might I use in the interim, please?

Comment: I’ll open a GitHub issue with full output and details, as that’s probably a better place (unless you greatly disagree). Can then link to any updated release here.

Comment: Either go back to 1.10.4 (without the -1) from CRAN, or latest 1.10.5 from GitHub should install.   But you still won't get multi-threaded benefits until you enable OpenMP on your machine.

Comment: Yes GitHub issue good please.

Comment: I would like to know why OpenMP is not installed. What OS are you using? You don't have GCC installed? Are you using mingw?

Comment: @Zboson Updated question with requested details, thanks.

Comment: ł@Serenthia, macOS - that explains it. I only use Linux. Maybe you can install the OpenMP runtimes but it depends what the binaries were built with as GCC and Clang use different OpenMP runtimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my mistake and pushed 1.10.4-2 to CRAN.

> - OpenMP on MacOS is now supported by CRAN and included in CRAN’s package binaries for Mac. But installing v1.10.4-1 from source on MacOS failed when OpenMP was not enabled at compile time, [#2409](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2409). Thanks to Liz Macfie and @fupangpangpang for reporting. The startup message when OpenMP is not enabled has been updated.

I've added an extra step to the release procedures to prevent this happening in future.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue yesterday and after some googling I managed to install `data.table` by specifying ~./R/Makevars.

In my case I used *macports* and installed gcc7. Which under *macports* are referenced by gcc-mp-7 and g++-mp-7

So to specify the compiler to use these instead of the default clang on macOS you need to create a file ~./R/Makevars . Then add the following lines:

> CC=gcc-mp-7  -fopenmp
>     CXX=g++-mp-7 -fopenmp

You should also be able to do the same with newer versions of `clang` just change the `gcc-mp-7` to `clang-omp` (or something equivalent depending on where it's installed) and don't forget the same `-fopenmp` flag in order to enable multi threading.

Comment: Or follow [the instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation#openmp-enabled-compiler-for-mac).